# Motion Blur problem (backwards)

Tags: texturing, blur

So I have this strange problem with motion blur in blender.
White car, marked on a picture as a red circle 1.

Setup: 1 frame basic postion, 2 frame aprox 0,5 metre to the left. Car is one object in this scene (joined).
Active motion blur in render tab with "start on frame" and Shutter set to "1.0".
Car is moving from right to left, but for some reason rendered motion blur looks like it goes backwards (wheel)..

Can someone explain me what is wrong?
[image]